# Tomcat setenv.sh not being picked up

Tags: linux, tomcat9

I have tomcat9 on linux as an on demand service, go into /bin and start.  I have a simple setenv.sh, shown below, that now fails show second below.  Everything is standard no other changes.  TC does startup how I need those options working.  How could this have gone from working to non-working.  How can I get again working and loading the setenv.sh?

> setenv.sh:  CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Djasypt.encryptor.password=123

on startup or shutdown this first message.  of course catalina.sh is in the executing directory.

> ./catalina.sh: 1: /usr/tomcat/tc9/bin/setenv.sh:
> -Djasypt.encryptor.password=123: not found

Comment: Problem still occurs even with both set to executable.

Comment: This isn't and never has been a valid variable assignment in a shell script. To assign a value with a space, you need to use `CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Djasypt.encryptor.password=123"`